# Visual studio 2017 closing file on saving, accidently

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2017, when using ctrl+s to save current editing file, the file would closed automaticly sometime.  Not always happen but quite a big chance it would.

It only happens to the .net core projects, because those projects automaticly include new files by default. Doesn't require use to add the new file.  VS 2017 creates a temporary file (unknown reason) when saving file.  For example, when save a "abc.cs" file, it automaticly creates a temp file named "abc~[guid].cs".  Although the temporary file removed after shot period, still catched by the VS itself as part of project sometime.  I suspect this causes the editing file being closed sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was a bug in Win 10.  Now all fine after recent update...